# Font-size is very small in FitText.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fittextjs

when I first open my page, my `h1` element's font-size shows very small. When I resize it, it automatically becoming huge. I want to know what is the problem with my code?

```
$('h1').fitText(0.273);
```

I didn't write font-size property in h1's css code. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with pure css *font-size: 1em*? I mean, do you really need a jquery plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i see fittext make it scalable. so you make 18/4*(browser scale). In sample with 0.273 font size is 220px, your font size about 18px
try to set
`$('h1').fitText(1);` 
or more